# Accessing a shared memory

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-assertions, system-verilog-dpi

I am trying to verify a sMEM design using assertions in systemVerilog 
however I got a problem I did not Know How to solve it : 
I am supposed to verify if:

> On rising edge of CLKA, when BLKA is 1 and RWA is 1, data is
>   read at ADDRA address of the RAM and the result is available
>   at DOUTA.

in my design the RAM is defined as **shared variable**

so how can I write assertions ?

Answer (score 0):

An assertion is not something I would use to verify a memory. Assertions are best for verifying protocols, not functionality. And since your memory is likely a vendor macro, theres no need for you to test its internal functionality. You mainly need to test the connectivity to the memory. There are pre-defined tests that involve writes followed by reads for memory verification.

Comment: Sorry Mr Dave I did a mistake
First my mem is defined as a shared variable not generic 
what I want to know is weather I can reach a variable using assertions or not   
thank you

Comment: Assertions can access any static variable. What do you mean by "shared variable"? That is not SystemVerilog terminology.

Comment: my design is written with VHDL 
what I meant by shared variable is that MEM can be accessed by many module 'sMEM' 'dMEM' 'ENPMEM'